# Bootstrap plugin/library download

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I downloaded the Bootstrap 3 build on this site,

[X-editable](https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/)

Going to be using it for my profile forms.

This will probably sound dumb but this is the first time i've used bootstrap to this extent and thus my first time downloading a bootstrap library so i don't know how to install it or where to place it in my files.

I'm using CodeIgniter3, I have an assets folder in my root along with my application folder, system folder, and user_guide folder.

and this is what my assets look like. Where do i put my newly downloaded bootstrap library? it does not state in the website, probably assumed all potential users would know and i'm probably looking like a unicorn right now.

I think i was overthinking it, in any case i just wanted to make sure i was doing things correctly. The x-editable library after i downloaded has the js and css files for it but it also has this other folder named inputs-ext with 3 more folders and a css and js inside each folder.

[image]

EDIT: After i calmed down, i just copied everything to my assets folder, my only question is regarding the inputs-ext. Do i copy all contents inside of it to the 'css' and 'js' folder? or keep them as they are, inside the inputs-ext and just copy it inside assets folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everyone's a unicorn at first! Bootstrap provides stylesheets and stuff that you can use like any other stylesheet you've made. Place the files in your site directory and link them in your HTML file, again like any other stylesheet (or script, etc. depending on what you're using). Then you can just add classes and they'll be pulled from the linked sheets.

Comment: what about the other folder named inputs-ext? download the file for me and look at it.

Comment: https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/docs.html Relevant documentation. From what I see it's just a different library and you can do different stuff with it.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a view, you will have to provide a path to the file within the head tag. I would recommend that you place it in your css directory. You may also want to consider using a CDN because it generally loads faster due to browser caching.

Example:

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
</head>
```

If you do not want to use a CDN, you can replace the href link above with the path to where you save Bootstrap. Most likely something along the lines of  '/assets/css/bootstrap.css'.

Per your edit, keep them as they are inside inputs-ext and copy that to the assets folder. Inputs-ext will need to be inside the x-editable library, in the same directory location it was when you downloaded it so that it can reference the code properly.

Comment: My original intention in not using a cdn was because sometimes ill use my laptop outside and i probably won't have internet connection.

Comment: Ok. So place it in your css directory then.